# ng-show doesn't keep up with ng-animation for scaling down in a dropdown

Tags: css, ng-animate

I have a dropdown that I want a scaling down animation to show when the dropdown opens and closes. I have a CODEPEN [**here**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/pRNLwo) with the code for you to experiment in.

I slowed it down to a 10 sec animation (not the final speed obviously) just for you to see what I mean. The items are scaling down at the speed I instructed (10 sec) but the items below won't come down until the ng-animation is completed. This causes overlap.

This is what I have in my HTML

```
<div class="cnt">
    <md-list ng-click="menuIsOpen = 1" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
        <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </md-list>
    <div class="sub-menu" ng-show="menuIsOpen===1" ng-animate="'animate'" >
        <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data"  >
            <md-button>
                <div layout="row" flex="">
                    <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                        <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
    </div>

    <md-list ng-click="menuIsOpen = 2" layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
        <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </md-list>
    <div class="sub-menu" ng-show="menuIsOpen===2" ng-animate="'animate'" >
        <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in data">
            <md-button>
                <div layout="row" flex="">
                    <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                        <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-animation:2s scaleIn ease;
    animation:2s scaleIn ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleIn {
    From {
        transform-origin:  top;
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
        -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
        -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
        -o-transform: scaleY(0);
        transform: scaleY(0);
    }
    To {
        transform-origin:  top;
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
        -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
        -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
        -o-transform: scaleY(1);
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
}

@keyframes scaleIn {
    From {
            transform-origin:  top;
          -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
          -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
          -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
          -o-transform: scaleY(0);
          transform: scaleY(0);
    }
        To {
          transform-origin:  top;
          -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
        -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
        -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
        -o-transform: scaleY(1);
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
}
```

I am essentially trying to reproduce the same animation as in the angular material website seen [**here**](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/)

p.s. any different approach or idea that doesn't require too much change overall, I am open to it. I am hoping for a css modification, but I know that it may not be that easy after all. I am hopeful though :)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not entirely familiar with angular but the demo you linked to animates via height attribute while you do it with scale. Also, you have an animation from 0 pixels to 30 which is what's holding up the menu and makes it snap down. It travels from 0 to 30px height during animation and once the animation class is removed it takes it's proper place.

Comment: @SergChernata While adjusting those parameter, I still get no closer to the desired effect. if I  remove the 30px nothing shows. If I change it to 100% it opens forn the center outwards not from top to bottom. I'm sure something is not right. I can't figure out what

Comment: Oh I know, I can't get it to work either lol But that's because I don't know Angular that well and I don't want to post you a jquery solution or something random :)

Comment: I can probably pass a jquery solution into a directive and work it that way. Go for it. It wouldn't hurt

Comment: @SergChernata you do at least need to be aware of the ng-animate classes that are in play from Angular tho. So I guess, to correct my last statement, a jquery solution won't probably work. I believe this is a strictly css3 solution. I'm just not too knowledgeable at handling css transitions

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna put this on hold. If no-one else answers in a couple of days I might look again. I'm equally comfortable with jquery and css animation but this is internal to angular.

Comment: @SergChernata fair enough. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

After a litte bit trial and error I think I found a [SOLUTION](http://codepen.io/theoretisch/pen/pRWEgZ).
If you animate not the div around (`sub-menu`) your `md-menu-item`s but the item itself, it will work.

I just added `ng-if="menuIsOpen===1"` to your `md-menu-item` (deleted the `ng-show="menuIsOpen===1` from the `sub-menu`) and changed the animation as follows:

```
md-menu-item.ng-enter{
    -webkit-animation:3s move ease;
    animation:3s move ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    From {
        margin-bottom:-50px;
    }
    To {
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
}


@keyframes move {
    From {
        margin-bottom:-50px;
    }
    To {
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
}
```

Now the size of every item in the menu is animated.
I cheated a little bit with `margin-bottom`, but `height` was still not working.

---

I think you have two options. ( At least I can't think of anything more.)
Or maybe three, see above.

1.You can change the height and add `transform-origin: top;` like here:

```
    @keyframes scaleIn {
  From {
     transform-origin:  top;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    height: 0px;
  }
  To {
     transform-origin:  top;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
    height: 190px;
  }
}
```

With `transform-origin` it will scale from the top and not from the middle.
BUT then you have to adjust the height every time you change the number of menu items.

2. You write it new (is probably nothig for you because you wont change much). I think there are definitely easier solutions like your posted example. e.g. see [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/d84prbn6kXsNB24iKWv8?p=preview)

Only the styles are missing and everything works.

I tried to change the height to % too, but that just never worked.
Even add some divs and change some positions nothing happens.
So maybe someone else has a better solution.

Comment: A for effort, but not reeeaaally a solution. And I'm only saying this because that's about how far I got as well.

Comment: I know, I tried a lot to figure out why its not working, but without any solution. Its strange that it only works with px and not %. I tried it with `margin-top` instead of `height` and there % worked pretty good. But anyway I really dont know why he makes all this so complicated. There are much easier solutions in angular. (But maybe he needs it so complicated) I'm curious about any other better solution!

Comment: I can't use the example you posted from Plunker because it needs Bootstrap to get that collapse functionality. This system uses Material Design instead. I'd hate to load an entire framework just for one little thing

Comment: ahh ok, thats an argument.

Comment: @theoretisch GREAT SOLUTION! After speeding the animation to the normal speed, it looks amazing specially in my system. Thanks man. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I wasn't to slow only just got time to look at this properly.

[Edited Codepen](http://codepen.io/dibdab/pen/pRwBxz)

Now to start your main problem was using CSS animations rather then transitions. With transitions being better for this as you are transitioning from one state(open) to another(closed). Rather then a complex animation with no defined start or end state.

So what I've done is change your classes:

```
.sub-menu{
    background: #333;
    max-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.sub-menu.ng-hide{
max-height: 0;
}

.sub-menu.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: max-height 700ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

.sub-menu.ng-hide-add {
    transition: max-height 600ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}
```

They now use `transisiton`. As well as `max-height` rather than `height` so that no specific `height` value needs to be given to the `submenu` to fully show it. Also using `cubic-bezier` for smoother transitioning.

Also I removed the `ng-animate="'animate'"` directives on elements as it isn't needed, it is the old way of adding animations. All classes are now managed by the `ng-show` directive and there is no `ng-animate` directive. The [current ngAnimate docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) can give more info about the classes.

The only other change made was to move the `ng-show` to the div with the `submenu` class, which was just so an extra class didn't need to be created for the `<ul>`.

Comment: I'm checking it on my phone and it looks good so far. I'll look at it further when I get to the office. Thanks

Comment: Looks good on desktop too! But I'm curious if someone knows why % not working. Is there something missing ?

Comment: For percentages to work there needs to be a fixed height in their somewhere. Which means each `submenu` would need a container with fixed height around it. So it can expand to 100% of that fixed height container.

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. I have no animation whatsoever. Not sure why it works in codepen but not in my code. :/

Comment: Ok, So I went through it extensively and still couldn't figure out why cubic-bezier doesn't work. But the method I applied does, except the scaleY may not be the best animation. I did some changes to it. Perhaps you can help me with a different animation type that could work better?

Comment: Only thing I can think of if classes are correct is are you using matching and up to date versions of angular and nganimate and is the ng animate dependency in you app correctly

Comment: Can switch out `cubic-bezier` for CCS premade like `ease`

Comment: Or other possible values and their descriptions instead of cubic curves can be seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)